# Como chamar a conexão dentro de uma função

Tags: php

**defines.php**

```
$HOST = "localhost";
$USER = "root";
$PASS = "";
$DB = "banco";
```

**config.php**

```
function conexao(){
    try{
        include_once("defines.php");
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$HOST.";dbname=".$DB."",$USER,$PASS);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $conn;
}
```

**func.php**

Estou tentando incluir essa conexão nessa função

```
include "pdo/config.php";
$conn = conexao ();

function noticias($conn){
    // Faz algo
}
```

Porém está dando muitos erros

> Notice: Undefined variable: HOST in /home/vol8_6/epizy.com/epiz_23239906/htdocs/pdo/config.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: DB in /home/vol8_6/epizy.com/epiz_23239906/htdocs/pdo/config.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: USER in /home/vol8_6/epizy.com/epiz_23239906/htdocs/pdo/config.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: PASS in /home/vol8_6/epizy.com/epiz_23239906/htdocs/pdo/config.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: conn in /home/vol8_6/epizy.com/epiz_23239906/htdocs/pdo/config.php on line 9
>
> Warning: Missing argument 1 for noticias(), called in /home/vol8_6/epizy.com/epiz_23239906/htdocs/aqv/lancamentos.php on line 11 and defined in /home/vol8_6/epizy.com/epiz_23239906/htdocs/func/var.php on line 4

Comment: Não está carregando o arquivo `defines.php`. Troque o `include`/`include_once` por `require_once`. Dessa forma ele gera um erro e para a execução do script caso não consiga incluir o arquivo. Aliás, pq vc fez um arquivo só com os dados da conexão e outro com a conexão? Sendo que o arquivo da conexão foi denominado `config.php`... Convenhamos: usuário, senha, e outras informações referentes ao banco de dados também são configurações. Deveriam estar no arquivo `config.php`, não?!

Comment: Nos seus arquivos php tem a tag "<?php  ?>" ?

Comment: @WandersonRodrigo Devemos presumir que sim. Senão o interpretador do PHP não iria gerar os erros... Certo?!

Comment: tem sim Wanxerson, nao deu certo Lip, mesmos erros, sobre o arquivo defines era pro codigo ficar mais limpo

Comment: Vou formular uma resposta e você dá um Ctrl+C > Ctrl+V. Posso mudar um pouco a estrutura do seu projeto?!

Comment: @LipESprY se funcionar sim, pq vou chamar essa funcao em mais de uma pagina

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a estrutura do seu projeto:

```
/pdo/defines.php
/pdo/config.php
/funcs.php
```

## /pdo/defines.php

```
<?php

$conexaoPDO = array(
    'drive' => 'mysql',     // Se for usar MySQL, não precisa mexer (ah vá)
    'host' => 'localhost',  // Host do banco de dados. Localmente = localhost
    'usuario' => 'root',    // Usuário
    'senha' => '',          // Senha
    'database' => 'teste',  // Nome do banco de dados
    'charset' => 'utf8'     // Charset - Recomendo usar o mesmo em todo seu projeto
);
```

## /pdo/config.php

```
<?php

function getPDO() {
    try {
        require_once('defines.php');
        $pdoConn = new PDO(
            (
                $conexaoPDO['drive']
                .':host='
                .$conexaoPDO['host']
                .';dbname='
                .$conexaoPDO['database']
            ),
            $conexaoPDO['usuario'],
            $conexaoPDO['senha'],
            array(
                \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => (
                    'SET NAMES '
                    .$conexaoPDO['charset']
                )
            )
        );
        $pdoConn->setAttribute(
            \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
            \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        return $pdoConn;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
        die('Erro ao conectar-se com o banco de dados!');
    }
}
```

## /func.php

```
<?php

require_once('pdo/config.php');

function noticias($pdoConn){
    // Faz algo
}

//getPDO()->prepare('SELECT ...');
//getPDO()->execute();
//getPDO()->query('SELECT ...');
```

Isso deve resolver de vez seu problema.

---

Considerações que deve tomar:

1. Se colocar a conexão do PDO dentro de alguma função e os dados vindo de um outro arquivo, deve carregar ele (`defines.php`) dentro da função. Se for carregar fora da função, precisa declarar as variáveis do arquivo `defines.php` como globais. Mais detalhes na documentação: [PHP - Escopo de variáveis](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php);
2. Sempre que for carregar algo que é **requerido** no funcionamento do seu projeto, use `require` ou `require_once`. A diferença que o `require_once` não vai permitir que o mesmo arquivo seja carregado mais de uma vez. Caso falhe em carregar o arquivo, ele pára a execução do script e retorna um erro (`php.ini` deve estar configurado para exibir o erro direto na página em que estiver navegando);
3. De quebra, aprimorei sua conexão com o PDO. Mais detalhes na documentação: [PHP - PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php).
4. Repliquei os códigos e a estrutura no meu [GitHub/sopt-como-chamar-a-conexao-dentro-de-uma-funcao](https://github.com/lipespry/sopt-como-chamar-a-conexao-dentro-de-uma-funcao). Pode baixar direto lá.

Comment: Deu erro 500 no config.php